# Typescript Discriminated Unions typesafety not working on child object?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm using Typescript 4 attempting to create an object with a property which uses discriminated-unions, but the type safety appears to not work?

```js
export enum StageType {
    PULL = 'pull',
    FILTER = 'filter',
}

export enum StageMetricProperty {
    IMPORTED = 'imported',
    SKIPPED = 'skipped',
    PIPED = 'piped',
    ERRORS = 'errors',
    PROCESSED = 'processed',
    SENT = 'sent',
    SAVED = 'saved',
}

// Pull stage metrics
export interface PullMetrics {
    [StageMetricProperty.IMPORTED]?: number;
    [StageMetricProperty.PIPED]?: number;
    [StageMetricProperty.ERRORS]?: number;
}
export interface PullReportStage { 
    type: StageType.PULL;
    name: string;
    args: string[];
    status: StageStatus;
    errors: string[];
    metrics: PullMetrics;
}

// Filter Stage Metrics
export interface FilterMetrics {
    [StageMetricProperty.SKIPPED]?: number;
    [StageMetricProperty.PIPED]?: number;
    [StageMetricProperty.ERRORS]?: number;
}
export interface FilterReportStage {
    type: StageType.FILTER;
    name: string;
    args: string[];
    status: StageStatus;
    errors: string[];
    metrics: FilterMetrics;
}

export type ReportStage =
    | PullReportStage
    | FilterReportStage;
```

With the above definition I attempt to create my FilterReportStage object (below), but Typescript never reports any errors with objects inside the `FilterReportStage.metrics` property, although it does correctly report errors on the top level `metric: FilterMetrics` object?

```js
const metric: FilterMetrics = {
    [StageMetricProperty.IMPORTED]: 123, // <-- Correctly parsed as invalid (as expected).
    [StageMetricProperty.PIPED]: 123, // <-- Valid
};

const sample = {
    type: StageType.FILTER,
    name: 'utils:command',
    args: [],
    errors: [],
    metrics: {
        [StageMetricProperty.IMPORTED]: 123, // <-- Invalid, Typescript does not report aby errors.
        [StageMetricProperty.PIPED]: 123, // <-- Valid
    } as FilterMetrics,
    status: StageStatus.PENDING
} as FilterReportStage;
```

Is anyone able to guide me as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (eg, `as FilterMetrics`), you're telling typescript "I know better than you do, so don't check my work here. Just assume it's the type I say it is". So since you've told typescript not to check your work, it doesn't.

If you want type checks then use standard types (eg, `: FilterReportStage`), not type assertions:

```
const sample: FilterReportStage = {
    type: StageType.FILTER,
    name: 'utils:command',
    args: [],
    errors: [],
    metrics: {
        [StageMetricProperty.IMPORTED]: 123, // <--- it points out the error here
        [StageMetricProperty.PIPED]: 123,
    },
    status: StageStatus.PENDING
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMowIYHNgAqAnmMHAN4BQcNcACgKoAyTcAvHAORjIA2vnADTVaAMQCSTAgFEASuy4AzAJa8YwKEMoBfSpVCRYCFOix5gZmMgDOFOOICydAPKyZAEUH1pAOXfifAHFdfXBoeCQ0TBx8B2AYKGUAYzooCFJYIgoRGkcXN2l3BU5lVEN1ABMtWkwAaXE6OkLi6wBrZTBSKuEaugbmjm4O4G6cuDlZVwxijTSoa2raOkmAYWkMDAGuMDSk4GtrEcWaTZ8CFqQYY8wAQQA1Lc5rbAA3I%20EQgHpP%20j5eOGsMTIqHiiSS1lC5TgykQ6igimwe1%20-DiCWStioNQA2mZYqDkql0hoYEQAHR5VweAC6AH4AFxwEwAIw0AG4xjigaiwYSMiTSX0mu5aQzmWyObjgNyCWk%20WSJlMRYy0CyoOzdAZwtDYRoEUi6H9ZMBypK7GMSaQGZLiKQBcwmOyaohsCCGYDEohcI7aNgoLhrG60Z6sVTvTRAdgrAHouZLDYwwgoHNo%206YbgQwmQWjwQyDSj8eD1XpvnBRKo4TH8HBpeDIVqYXC9WQy2oNDWMRKuQXecSyRh6o1CkqxWrO%20Yaz3MgL%20sL6crUKqE5zx93Zb3SQrZBhhyrxRqwkYG7rEc3yxojSagdkahbgFagTbgKSJFI5Anna6AUGvWNff7Ax66ahmMEZRvesY4FGCazNAKbfhmYxZmC0YtnC7ZFnWRi3nAF7hKabBjAAPsivC4bAkpEaWZ5QGRMCSuyYxJBAiCAnASHJAyqFtgWtgcJitDLni2aTvyFIFMKDIAIwAEwAMw9AJkoTmuU6CkOUlyR8DFMSx8DPGUvB3lRrY0caeFXnx5okEZ1rWc%20kgyLICk0B%20RmcMgMCqAGTGoKg2CIKMNR-tGIbOYmyYMqFiE8Qy-E1DQglSquRJTmJ1IafJYzYkpyVytOQpUhlYXaGFoE2OB%20BxtYAq%20P4QQ6KyQA)

Comment: @E_mE Please don't forget accept the answer if it helpful. This is the best way to thank